# setBackground is undecorated JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, cardlayout

Okay.. I'm rewriting this question..

I've found out that `setUndecorated()` was not the problem.

The problem was `setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)`

After some tries, the the `CardLayout` was showing the right result

when the alpha channel of the background was 1 (fully opaque).

And else it was showing the wrong result.

```
public SmartPhone() {
    super("SmartPhone");

    setUndecorated(true); 
    setBackground(new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, .5f));

    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    init(); start();

    device = this;
}
```

This is my constructor. `init()` is method creating the layout and `start()` is the method adding `MouseAdapter`.

Is there anything wrong with my `setBackground()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When switching between components in a `CardLayout`, use the `CardLayout.show()` method, don't use `setVisible()` directly.  Like this:

```
CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
String oneStr = "One";
String twoStr = "Two";
JLabel oneLabel = new JLabel(oneStr);
JLabel twoLabel = new JLabel(twoStr);
cardPanel.add(oneLabel, oneStr);
cardPanel.add(twoLabel, twoStr);

cardLayout.show(cardPanel, oneStr);//sets "One" visible
cardLayout.show(cardPanel, twoStr);//sets "Two" visible
```

See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment and great tip. But again, it doesn't work.. :(
I've updated my question and my code.
Please notice me if there's any problem.

Answer (score -1):

Um... Solved..?

I don't know what I did, but after doing some other project,

Components were printed well..!